# Adblock hinders ge.tt's working

Tags: adblock

I use Adbock on Chome and it works fine, but it prevents ge.tt form showing my folders.

Any Ideas?

Thanks a lot in advance
Daniel

Comment: How is it related to programming?

Comment: Why should it? But if you insist, the question is how to programm adblock, so it works with ge.tt.

Comment: Why? http://stackoverflow.com/about Have you looked at https://code.google.com/p/adblockforchrome/wiki/Support

Comment: i see your point, but isn't your objection and content of your link #1 refuted by the word #1 in your link #2? thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

exception rule **@@||ge.tt/$document** does it nicely.